# Как убрать пробел перед <?xml

Tags: php, xml

При генерации xml файла ставится пробел в начале.  Как найти, в каком файле php остался пробел если файлов много?

Comment: Вы уверены, что вы знаете PHP, если вы не можете написать скрипт, который проверит наличие пробелов в начале файлов?

Comment: У меня начальный уровень знаний PHP.

Comment: Что ж, тогда идите изучать работу с файлами. Там кода на пять строчек. `file_get_contents`, `scandir` и др.

Comment: @Discord незнание топикастером основ работы с файлами - не повод закрывать вопрос :)

Comment: @PashaPash Когда будет "у меня такой код, и вот здесь проблема с поиском" — поменяю своё мнение. А пока RTFM, я даже ссылки дал. Осталось только прочитать описание и добавить цикл/рекурсию.

Comment: @Discord с чего вы взяли что эту задачу вообще надо решать кодом на php??

Comment: @PashaPash Было бы странно, имея под рукой PHP, не написать скрипт на три строчки, который решает проблему. Ну вот pcregrep — это что за некроссплатформенная костылина с мифическими аргументами? Ну нафиг.

Comment: @Discord есть еще findstr под винду. и наверняка что-то под мак - но сходу не скажу

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно найти проблемный файлы любой утилитой для поиска с поддержкой регексов:

```
pcregrep -rMl '([\s\n]+)(?=\<\?php)' *
```

<sub>Решение честно скопировано с [pcregrep for finding all files with extra space before php opening tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17588720/1988244)</sub>

Comment: Хм, окей, в PHP рекурсивный обход директорий печальный какой-то... Готовой функции нет, засада.

Answer (score 2):

Учитесь полагаться на доступные вам инструменты, которые вы знаете, а не на магические однострочники, аргументы которых вы наверянка не знаете наизусть. Например, если все ваши файлы лежат в одной папке, то обход тривиален:

```
foreach (scandir('.') as $file)
    if (preg_match('#\.php#i', $file) && preg_match('#\s+<\?#s', file_get_contents($file)))
        echo "$file\n";
```

Если нужно пройтись по папкам рекурсивно, то понадобится дополнительная функция:

```
function scandirall ($dir)
{
    $files = [];
    foreach (array_diff(scandir($dir), ['.', '..']) as $file)
        if (is_file("$dir/$file"))
            $files[] = "$dir/$file";
        else
            foreach (scandirall("$dir/$file") as $subfile)
                $files[] = $subfile;
    return $files;
}

foreach (scandirall('.') as $file)
    if (preg_match('#\.php#i', $file) && preg_match('#\s+<\?#s', file_get_contents($file)))
        echo "$file\n";
```